# How to build nestjs installable and removable module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am building a nest.js Application and I want to have an addons module
this module can download a module from my repo, then install and register it to the application while it's running without a restart
also to remove it without reloading the application
how to do that ?
Thanks